# Commutation relations in quantised Yang-Mills

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, commutator, lie-algebra, yang-mills

Consider Yang-Mills theory with gauge group $G$. Let $\{T^a\}$ be a basis for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, so that the connection coefficients can be written as $A_\mu = A_\mu^aT^a$.

In the wavefunctional representation, the electric field operator $\hat{E}^i=\hat{E}^{i,a}T^a$ acts as: $$\tag{$*$}\hat{E}^{i,a}(x) = -i\frac{\delta}{\delta A_i^a(x)}.$$

I'm quite confused about the electric field commutation relations . Namely:

(1) Is $[\hat{E}^{i,a}(x),\hat{E}^{j,b}(y)]=0$ for spacelike $x,y$?
(2) Is $[\hat{E}^{i,a}(x),\hat{E}^{j,b}(x)]=0$ for all $x$?

In both cases, I find it conceivable that the RHS could instead be nonzero, depending somehow on the structure constants of the Lie algebra. My confusion arises since there are two separate types of noncommutation happening: "classical noncommutation" of lie algebra elements, and "quantum noncommutation" on Hilbert space.

A satisfactory answer would prove or disprove (1) and (2) directly from the definition $(*)$.

Comment: Do you know how to prove the commutation relations for a scalar field in the wavefunctional picture? In particular, $[\hat{\phi}(\vec{x}), \hat{\phi}(\vec{y})]=[\hat{\pi}(\vec{x}), \hat{\pi}(\vec{y})]=0$ and $[\hat{\phi}(\vec{x}), \hat{\pi}(\vec{y})]=i \delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$ (where $\hat{\phi}$ is the field and $\hat\pi$ is the momentum). Note in the Schrodinger picture, the operators are not time dependent, so I have only included dependence on the spatial variables $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$. The Yang-Mills case is similar, just with more indices, so it's good to understand the scalar case.

Comment: @Andrew $[\phi,\phi]=0$ is by assumption. Defining $\pi=\partial\mathcal{L}/\partial{\dot{\phi}}$, we can show $[\phi,\pi]=i\delta$ using the argument in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/685812/314376) answer to another question of mine. I'm not sure how I'd prove the $[\pi,\pi]=0$ commutator - perhaps you could enlighten me?

Comment: Actually I think that argument is using the Schwinger-Dyson equations (following from the path integral), not really the Schrodinger picture per se. I think it is simpler than you think. In the field basis, the operator $\phi$ is just multiplication by a scalar, so the fields commute. Meanwhile, $\pi(x) = - i \delta/\delta\phi(x)$. You can think of functional derivatives as a partial derivative (imagine discretizing space, then the functional derivative at $x$, up to a normalization, is the partial derivative wrt the field value at $x$). Partial derivatives commute, the $\pi$'s commute.

Comment: Meanwhile, $[\phi(x), \pi(y)] = i \delta^3(x-y)$ because we vary the field at every spacetime point independently, so the partial derivative of $\phi(x)$ wrt $\phi(y)$ is zero unless $x=y$. So, $\delta \phi(x) / \delta \phi(y) = \delta^3(x-y)$.

Comment: Sure, the difficulty of the problem you gave depends on what we take as our starting point. I prefer to always start with the path integral, so certain things are more difficult. Using your assumptions, the problem is indeed trivial.

Comment: You may want to clarify this in your question then, since you mention you are working in the "wavefunctional representation", which I took to be the Schrodinger picture.

Comment: Regardless, are you saying that both (1) and (2) are true in my original question? If so, I'd really appreciate a reference which states it explicitly, since I've not been able to find one, and I don't want to put all my faith in stackechange!

Comment: I'm not saying (1) or (2) are true. Actually (2) doesn't look right to me, I would have thought there would be structure constants on the right hand side, but I was assuming you had gotten them from somewhere. I'm just saying that you should understand the scalar field case before tackling Yang Mills. (Hence why I am leaving a comment and not an answer).

Comment: Also just as a general comment, the path integral is great, but it's not a good starting point for everything. Unitarity of Yang Mills is very difficult to establish using only the path integral without referencing the operator formalism (I actually don't know if anyone knows how to do it).